# @override annotation

Tags: java

Do I need to put `@Override` annotation when I implement an interface (not override an abstract class)?

And what does `@Override` annotation achieve?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Java 5, you must not add `@Override` when implementing a method inherited from an interface, in Java 6, you should (or you'll get a compiler warning).

`@Override` asserts that a method is intended to override something, and will cause the compiler to notify you should this not or no longer be the case, for instance because the method you are overriding has been renamed.

Comment: The compiler warning is typically configurable; e.g. Eclipse has it off by default.

Answer (score 23):

It breaks your compile if you say you override something when you really didn't.

If you don't put an @Override tag, but according to the compiler you didn't override anything, you have a silent bug you don't know about. With the @Override tag, you do know about it, and you know about it NOW, not later.

You **NEVER NEED** to put an @Override annotation. But I'd recommend doing it every time.

Answer (score 13):

The `@Override` annotation informs the compiler that the element is meant to override an element declared in a superclass.

It is not required, but it will generate a compile error if that method actually does not correctly override a method in a superclass.

Comment: Best answer! Very simple. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 8):

`@override` basically forces the compiler to check that you really are overriding an existing base-class method, and not simply (accidentally) creating a new method.

Answer (score 2):

It's good practice to always use `@Override`, as it can help you preemptively catch some otherwise insidious bugs.  It also enhances code clarity.  For example, check out the example given in *Effective Java*, Chapter 6, Item #36:

```
// Can you spot the bug? - Page 176
package org.effectivejava.examples.chapter06.item36;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Bigram {
    private final char first;
    private final char second;

    public Bigram(char first, char second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public boolean equals(Bigram b) {
        return b.first == first && b.second == second;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 31 * first + second;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Bigram> s = new HashSet<Bigram>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
                s.add(new Bigram(ch, ch));
        System.out.println(s.size());
    }
}
```

This method may look fine at first glance, but it is in fact very broken!  The programmer didn't follow the contract of `equals(Object o)`, instead implementing `equals(Bigram b)`, which will *not* be called when doing things that depend on `equals()`; i.e., inserting instances of `Bigram` into a `Map`.  So, this will cause confusing, subtle wrong behavior that will be hard to track down, whereas if the programmer had just used `@Override` in the first place, the compiler would have immediately alerted them to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

NO, Java doesn't bind you to put an @Override annotation while implementing an interface. You can override the methods declared in interface as we normally do.
But, its a good practice to use an @Override annotation while overriding methods of an interface or any parent class including abstract class. 
Why? Because it helps us/compiler identify any problem in overriding a method at compilation itself.

For example: http://java-dive.blogspot.in/

```
 class Ball{
        public void bounce(){
        }
        } 

//////////////////////Override without @Override/////////////////////////////

    public class FootBall{
    public void bounce(String s){
    }
    }

//this will compile however new FootBall().bounce(); will call parent method.

//////////////////////Override with @Override/////////////////////////////

    public class FootBall{
    @Override
    public void bounce(String s){
    }
    }

//This will not compile as the parent class doent have any method with signature bounce(String s)
```